# Does tidal force continue to increase as a man falls into a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, many-body, tidal-effect

Small black holes have collosal tidal forces at their event horizons. But there are black holes large enough where a man can cross the event horizon without being ripped apart. But does the tidal force not increase after the crossing? Is it because space cascades downwards and helps alleviate the growing tidal pressure? This does make intuitive sense since a falling observer never reaches the singularity, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: What do you mean by “*a falling observer never reaches the singularity*”?

Comment: +1 as I also would like to see an answer with the math of the tidal forces inside. There is no gravity inside a Schwarzschild black hole, because the spatial gradient of the time dilation is zero in the Schwarzschild coordinates. With no gravity there should be no tidal forces inside, but I hope someone posts an answer with the proper math.

Comment: @safesphere, if I remember the math correctly, the singularity exists a finite distance away from the event horizon only from an outside observer's perspective. On the contrary, from a falling observer's perspective, there is an infinite amount of space that has already cascaded down previously and all of it must be traversed before reaching the singularity, which is almost impossible.